# How to use string.count command and use a starting point?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Simple question:
I'm new to programming and need to use the command string.count
I know that if I do

```
a="laringologo"
a.count("o")
```

it will give me the number of o's in the word.
How can I use the command if I want to count the number of o's after `"laringo"`?
I know the command works like
`string.count(s, sub[, start[, end]]` but I don't understand how to use it correctly

Comment: Technically, `string.count` is not a command but a method.

Comment: @sacul A method indeed. And I am not nitpicking but educating a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `start` argument to tell `count` at which index to start counting. In your case, you want it to start counting after the number of characters in "laringo", so you can do:

```
a="laringologo"

>>> a.count('o', len("laringo"))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

@sacul's answer is correct if/when you know that 'laringo' is always at the beginning of `a`. If it is not, as in the following example, then you should first find it, then skip it, and then count 'o's in the rest of the string:

```
a = "foobarlaringologo"
a.count('o', a.index('laringo') + len('laringo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

count() has three attributes `string.count(substring, start=…, end=…)` If you want to count substrings after a certain number of characters, the syntax would be `string.count('substring', numberOfCharacters)`. If "laringologo" is not necessarily the beginning of the string you can look for it with `string.find('substring')`

```
a="laringologo new to programming"
a.count("o", len(laringologo))
#or
b="header laringologo new to programming"
b.count("o", b.find('laringologo')+len('laringologo'))
```

Comment: The string to search for should be "laringo". You forgot the quotes in the 1st version. This will give funny output if the search string isn't found, since `.find` will return -1.